# Is composition of analytic functions itself analytic?

Tags: analyticity

Is composition of analytic functions itself analytic?

Is there a proof that, say,

$$f(x)=e^{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1}}$$

analytic?

Comment: The example you gave has some problems at $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro and what? these problems do not make it non-analytic and non-holomorphic.

Comment: Yes, it is still analytic on $(-\infty, -1)\cup (-1, 1)\cup (1, \infty)$.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro prove

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197737, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761148/

Answer (score 3):

The composition of analytic functions indeed is analytic. The fastest proof surely relies on complex analysis: every analytic function of one real variable is the restriction of a holomorphic function of one complex variable, so the statement is a consequence of the (complex variable) chain rule.

Comment: This requires first the proof that any differentiable complex function is analytic, which I think is a non-trivial theorem. Anyway, what about real analysis? Can this be proven without complex numbers?

Comment: I don't know. I guess that it can, but probably this requires quite a bit of algebra.

Comment: What do u think about this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834257/if-two-functions-are-equal-to-their-newton-series-is-their-composition-also-equ

Comment: "every analytic function of one real variable is the restriction of a holomorphic function" - this is not true. Take logarithm for example.

Comment: I don't see why this is a counterexample. There are branches of the complex logarithm that coincide with the real logarithm on $(0, \infty)$. Those are holomorphic.

Comment: @Anixx - For real analysis, see my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @mr_e_man which one?

Comment: Composition of real-analytic functions is real-analytic

Comment: @mr_e_man: you forgot the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4474145/8157 I could find your answer anyway, thank you for the notification.

Answer (score -2):

Your example is a composition/combination of several functions
$$
u(x) = e^x \\
v(x) = x^2 + 1\\
h(x) = x^2  - 1 \\
m(x, y) = x / y \\
f(x) = u( m( v(x), h(x) ) )
$$
The function $m$ is not very nice when $y = 0$, but $y = 0$ happens to be in the image of $h$.

What are you assuming is the domain of $f$? And are you asking "Is it analytic on that domain?"?