# If two functions are equal to their Newton series, is their composition also equal to its Newton series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-calculus

Suppose we have two real functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, both equal to their Newton series expansion (let's call such function Newton-analytic):

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}k \Delta^k f\left (0\right)$$

$$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}k \Delta^k g\left (0\right)$$

Is their composition $F(x)=f(g(x))$ also equal to its Newton series expansion (if it converges)?

$$F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}k \Delta^k F\left (0\right)$$

Comment: This is just like the linked question, except that now we cannot escape via complex analysis like I did there. :-) I guess that the answer is affirmative, though.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro there is no total analogy though. If we allow complex functions, then there is a counter-example, for instance, $g(x)=2\pi i x$, $f(x)=\exp(x)$. That's why I limited the question to real-valued functions.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro well, I has been given a counter-example: $f(x)=\sin(\pi \sqrt{x})$, $g(x)=x^2$