# local inverse of analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-functions, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:R^n\to R^n$ be an analytic map such that $df_a$ is invertible.
The "usual" local inversion theorem says that $f$ is locally invertible and that the inverse will be smooth.

I'm quite sure that, if $f$ is analytic, the inverse will be analytic too, but I cannot prove it.

I know [a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359330/is-the-inverse-of-a-real-analytic-function-still-analytic) in the case $n=1$ trough complex analysis.

This is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134267/proof-that-the-inverse-of-an-analytic-function-is-analytic-which-uses-only-real) with two differences :

- I don't mind passing trough complex analysis
- I need a statement on an open set of $R^n$, not an interval of R.
- I want a proof or a link, not a reference to a book (I do not have access to a math library)

Comment: The proof through complex analysis can be carried through also in more variables: extend $f$ to a neighborhood of $\mathbf{R}^n\subset\mathbf{C}^n$, prove that the differential of the extension is invertible at every point, and prove that the inverse of a holomorphic function (in several variables) is holomorphic

Comment: See exercise 14 and 15 on page 226 here: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf.

Comment: Also this one : https://books.google.com/books?id=jSeRz36zXIMC&pg=PA33 (got from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem))